# Modal dialog on Active Explorer Window only

Tags: outlook, vsto

I have a modal dialog in my form region. I am providing the form region as the owner of the dialog but it blocks access to Outlook main window as well as always appears on top of it.
Is it possible to have modal dialog on my active explorer window that is showing my form region and not on other Outlook windows?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible by design. A modal dialog will always be modal to the entire process, i.e. all windows belonging to the Outlook process will be blocked by your modal dialog.

As a workaround, you can make your dialog non-modal and bring it to the front whenever the explorer is activated (check for the [`Explorer.Activate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff867298.aspx) event).